# Php restricting the data insertion in mysql

Tags: php

I have a list box with two times i.e 12:00 to 2:00 and 2:00 to 4:00.I want to do that when someone submit the form (example a meeting reservation form) the timing inserted into the databse should be booked only for three times.when someone tries to insert the same time for the fourth time,it should give us message like (already booked).
help me to do this in php, mysql.
thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have a project to do, and want us to write it all for you...

Comment: no, not like that
i am just learning these things.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real question here, you should start the project and when you come up against a brick wall we can help you.

Here are some good resourcesL

Start by reading up on `PHP` - http://www.php.net

The mysql manual is also very helpful http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/manual-info.html

Comment: i am working on the project and almost done, but i need to book for similar time on three times,help me 
thnx